# Viewport is showing faces that should be hidden behind other faces

Tags: interface

I'm very new to blender, I'm following a tutorial to create a building. The viewport is set to shading, however it's showing the faces that should be out of view. I couldn't find a setting for this, mainly because I don't know what it is called. I tried Googling but I didn't know how to explain it.

How can I hide the faces that shouldn't be visible?
See below:

My viewport:

[image: This is my viewport]

The viewport in the tutorial:

[image: Tutorial]

Version 2.82.7

Comment: maybe you've activated the Show Whole Scene Transparent button (on the right of the header menu bar, shortcut alt Z)

Comment: That's the "Toggle X-Ray" option, this isn't enabled, toggling it on looks the same, just bolder edges.

Comment: This could be an issue with the drawing order due to the *Blend Mode* or perhaps backface culling is enabled and the normals point in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have blend mode (in material settings) turned to alpha blend. It is used in Eevee for transparency, alpha blend mode tells blender that it will use alpha channel from texture to calculate transparency.

However even without texture with alpha you will see this overlaying faces effect when this setting is chosen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. It's a fresh installation, and the plugin I used was called "Import Images as Planes". Everything else was default so I'm not sure why this got turned to Alpha Blend.